# How to add new Custom Title in Woocommerce My Account sidebar?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, endpoint

Hi i want to add new custom title and links into My Account page into my WooCommerce site.. Searched all documentation, and Stackoverflow topics, but not found sollution for my request.

This is title for what im asking for

[image]

Text Muj Ucet is My Account in english. :)

i want to add new title like is shown in image bellow:

[image]

This is WooCommerce Template Code for that part:

```
<?php


if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}
?>

<p><?php
/* translators: 1: user display name 2: logout url */
printf(
    __( 'Hello %1$s (not %1$s? <a href="%2$s">Log out</a>)', 'woocommerce' 
 ),
    '<strong>' . esc_html( $current_user->display_name ) . '</strong>',
    esc_url( wc_logout_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) )
);
?></p>

<p>Na nástěnce svého uživatelského účtu si můžete stáhnout své zakoupené 
produkty a faktury, upravit své osobní informace, změnit heslo nebo 
fakturační adresu.</p>

<?php
/**
 * My Account dashboard.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_account_dashboard' );

/**
 * Deprecated woocommerce_before_my_account action.
 *
 * @deprecated 2.6.0
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_my_account' );


/**
 * Deprecated woocommerce_after_my_account action.
 *
 * @deprecated 2.6.0
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_my_account' );

/* Omit closing PHP tag at the end of PHP files to avoid "headers already 
sent" issues. */
```

I want to add new one title bellow that sidebar. How to register a new title ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'display_account_new_link');
function display_account_new_link( $items ) {
    $items['new_link'] = __( 'New Link', 'text-domain' );
    return $items;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_new_link_endpoint', 'new_account_link_content' );
function new_account_link_content() {
    //include your display template here
    echo "Here goes you content";
}
```

After pasting this code in your plugin or in your theme function.php file this code will make a new link in the my account navigation sidebar, along with the template you want to assign this link. Here **new_link** is the slug for this navigation link. If you want to give some different slug you must rename new_link written everywhere in the given code. As soon as you click on this New Link it will redirect you to the Page Not Found Page. It can be solved by adding this code.

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_new_link_endpoint');
function register_new_link_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'new_link', EP_PAGES );
}
```

After pasting this code you must save your permalink once, by going to WordPress Dashboard->Settings->Permalinks and hit the save changes button.

Comment: Your Code only add new endpoint into current tab.

https://i.imgur.com/l7RlAvO.png?1

i want to add a new Title like "MŮJ ÚČET" is bellow all links from that category. Understand me?

Comment: woocommerce_after_account_navigation is the desired hook for you but it is ruining the whole structure. You may try this hook.

Comment: So  how to add a new title, or its impossible?

Comment: First try this code add_action('woocommerce_after_account_navigation','function_name');  function function_name(){echo '<h2>Title</h2>';} so you may know how structure is getting messed up. Another option would be to wrap this title under a span tag and manage the structure with css

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157156/discussion-between-drmtr-and-logan-young).